# Typescript utility type to transfor type property name from camel case into Pascal case

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have to use a REST API service that wrongly uses Pascal casing in its DTO's.
Is it possible to construct a utility type in Typescript that will transform a type with camel case property names into pascal case property names ?

Like this

```
type  Driver = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  active: boolean
}

type CamelToPascal<T> = ....

type CamelToPascal<Driver>
// result
type  Driver = {
  FirstName: string
  LastName: string
  Active: boolean
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can:

```js
type Driver = {
    firstName: string
    lastName: string
    active: boolean
}

type CamelToPascal<T extends string> = 
T extends `${infer FirstChar}${infer Rest}` ? `${Capitalize<FirstChar>}${Rest}` : never

type ToCamelCase<T> = {
    [Prop in keyof T as CamelToPascal<Prop & string>]: T[Prop]
}

// type Result = {
//     FirstName: string;
//     LastName: string;
//     Active: boolean;
// }
type Result = ToCamelCase<Driver>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXQlQN)

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336) you can find PR about intrinsic type `Capitalize` and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) about key remapping

`CamelToPascal` infers first char of a string, capitalizing it and adds to rest chars. Smth like this in pure js:

```js
const capitalize = (str: string) => {
    const [fst] = str;
    
    return `${fst.toUpperCase()}${str.slice(1)}`
}
```